# Parsing git log output in Java

Tags: java, git, parsing

I am trying to write parser logic for the following problem statement.

I generate a git log file which is has following format:

```
--hash--date--author
num of lines added, num of lines deleted    filepath1
num of lines added, num of lines deleted    filepath2
num of lines added, num of lines deleted    filepath3
```

Sample:

```
--a14582d--2016-01-25--Phillip Verheyden
5   1   pom.xml

--4a90ef6--2016-01-19--Phillip Verheyden
1   5   pom.xml

--2a23e26--2015-09-25--jefffischer
--4cd0ae4--2015-09-25--Reginald C Cole
28  23  admin/broadleaf-admin-module/src/main/java/org/broadleafcommerce/admin/server/service/handler/SkuCustomPersistenceHandler.java
1   1   admin/broadleaf-open-admin-platform/src/main/java/org/broadleafcommerce/openadmin/server/service/persistence/datasource/SandBoxConnection.java
```

Subsequent to parsing, we will be summing up the changes per file over period of time.

This approach is same as to what has been done by Adam tornhill in Code MAAT.
https://github.com/adamtornhill/code-maat#churn-by-entity

He has done some superb work in Clojure.

I would like to do the parsing using plain old java.

What approach should I take?

I am a newbie when it comes to text parsing which goes beyond something like a CSV.

Note: this exercise is for a open source project.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd say, why not use something like JGit, which lets you directly query the git repository? Then you don't need an intermediary representation or to parse the output of git commands.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I have considered that option and seem to think that the effort will be on the higher side.I did not see an api to fetch num of lines changed directly. Are you aware of any?

Comment: a DiffFormatter can generate diff between two trees, and a DiffAlgorithm can generate diff for two files

Comment: @SV Have a look at the [corresponding cookbook recipe](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowBranchDiff.java)

Comment: @TassosBassoukos and Jérémie B, thanks for the pointers. At this point I still feel that parsing the file will be faster, but I will do deeper investigation of approach suggested by you.

Comment: For easy text processing, how about using Python instead?

Comment: @Nayuki I will be extending an existing java framework.